# Miss-match discount price with 2 catalog price rule magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, catalog-price-rules

I have facing issues with catalog price rule. You can see below senario which you getting to help you.

I have a product which have price $77.00, sku - product1

I create two Catalog Price Rule for both are NOT LOGGED IN Group

**Rule 1:**

priority - 1

sku - product1

Apply - by percent

discount amount - 54%

Stop Further Rules Processing - yes

After applying discount and getting price on Product detail page is 35.42

**Rule 2:**

priority - 2

sku - sproduct1

Apply - by percent

discount amount - 40%

Stop Further Rules Processing - yes

After applying discount and getting price on Product detail page is 46.20

But when these both are active product price is 35.00. Don't getting what happening? It should show 35.42

can you please improve answer.
Thanks

Comment: are you sure you are getting price in decimal when any one of the rule is applied ? because magento by default rounds it off

Comment: if i apply one rule then it works properly